# Javascript "head" object scope

Tags: javascript

I took the code below from the book "JavaScript Enlightement". The code says that the first two statements return true but when I run the code in JSFiddle, the first to lines return "false" (the variables defined with the var keyword). Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body><script>
var myStringVar = 'myString';
var myFunctionVar = function() {};
myString = 'myString';
myFunction = function() {};
console.log('myStringVar' in window); // returns true
console.log('myFunctionVar' in window); // return true
console.log('myString' in window); // returns true
console.log('myFunction' in window); // return true
</script></body></html>
```

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: It would be courteous to provide a link to the fiddle when asking a question about jsfiddle...

Comment: You might find this interesting http://jsfiddle.net/V2uEb/1/ If you try this locally the result will be different.

Comment: @Juhana My question wasn't directly about JSFiddle, but I got your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jsFiddle, your code is embedded and doesn't run directly in `window` but in a callback called when the page is loaded.

If you want to test those cases, you have to run the code in a standard page or choose one of the `"no wrap"` options you have in the second menu in the left panel.

Comment: Or just select the "no wrap" option from the second dropdown list on the top left. http://jsfiddle.net/zEBm6/